# Spring: como o Jackson pode formatar uma resposta Json composta em objetos

Tags: java, spring, jackson

Bom, estou fazendo um projeto Spring juntamente com Spring-cloud-openFeign para integração com uma api da Fipe para acessar valores de carros. Veja a classe:

```
@Service
@FeignClient(name = "FipeService", url = "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1")
public interface FipeService {
    
    @GetMapping("/{type}/marcas")
    public List<FipeResponse> getBrands(@PathVariable String type);

    @GetMapping("/{type}/marcas/{brandCode}/modelos")
    public List<FipeResponse> getModels(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String brandCode);

    @GetMapping("/{type}/marcas/{brandCode}/modelos/{modelCode}/anos")
    public List<FipeResponse> getYears(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String brandCode, @PathVariable String modelCode);

    @GetMapping("/{type}/marcas/{brandCode}/modelos/{modelCode}/anos/{year}")
    public FipeResponse getPrice(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String brandCode, @PathVariable String modelCode, @PathVariable String year);
}
```

O FipeResponse é uma classe minha usada para o Jackson inserir o retorno da api nela, o que ele faz no método `getBrands()` pois a resposta Json é simples, um array somente com nome e código. Veja a classe:

```
public class FipeResponse {

private String nome;
private String codigo;
private String valor;

public FipeResponse(String nome, String codigo, String valor) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.valor = valor;
}

public FipeResponse(){

}

getters e setters
```

}

Porém, no segundo endpoint tenho um problema, o `getModels` retorna um array com modelos e anos (teste o link: https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/59/modelos) e o Jackson não consegue inserir no FipeResponse obviamente, mas, já tentei dentro do FipeResponse adicionar outras duas classes como composição, uma para modelos e outra para anos, ambos com nome e codigo de atributos somente, e inseri no FipeResponse assim:

```
public class FipeResponse {

private String nome;
private String codigo;
private String valor;
private List<FipeAnos> anos;
private List<FipeModelos> modelos;

public FipeResponse(String nome, String codigo, String valor, List<FipeAnos> anos, List<FipeModelos> modelos) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.valor = valor;
    this.anos = anos;
    this.modelos = modelos;
}

public FipeResponse(){

}

getters e setters
```

}

E mesmo assim o Jackson continua não conseguindo inserir os dados usando o endpoint `getModels()`, mas funciona normalmente usando `getBrands()`, consigo acessar os atributos e tudo. O que fiz de errado?

Comment: Não entendi o downvote na pergunta... Se for necessário maiores detalhes é só perguntar, agora dar -1 e não falar nada não resolve em absolutamente nada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetBrands : A requisição a esse endpoint retorna de fato uma lista:

```
[
  {
    "nome": "Acura",
    "codigo": "1"
  },
  {
    "nome": "Agrale",
    "codigo": "2"
  }...
]
```

o endpoint getModels retorna um objeto, e esse objeto contém uma lista de modelos :

```
{
  "modelos": [
    {
      "nome": "AMAROK CD2.0 16V/S CD2.0 16V TDI 4x2 Die",
      "codigo": 5585
    },
    {
      "nome": "AMAROK CD2.0 16V/S CD2.0 16V TDI 4x4 Die",
      "codigo": 5586
    },
    ....
}
```

Para obter a resposta desse endpoint você deve modelar um objeto que represente esse json, como por exemplo:

```
public class FipeModelo {
   public String modelo;
   public Integer codigo;
}

Public class FipeModelos {
   public List<FipeModelo> modelos;
}
```

presta atenção que o FipeModelos recebe uma Lista de FipeModelo e a variável se chama modelos, conforme a resposta que vem no endpoint que você passou.

E na classe de serviço do feign ficaria:

```
@GetMapping("/{type}/marcas/{brandCode}/modelos")
public FipeModelos getModels(@PathVariable String type, @PathVariable String brandCode);
```